# Rails dynamic progress bar from running task

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, progress-bar, activeadmin

I have a "long" task that is called by the browser. 
That I want to do is to create a dynamic progress bar that show the progress of the "behinds the scene" task in the same page or lightbox (without refreshing the page).

My idea is to use a JQuery bar like this: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar

My question is:

How can I call a JQuery (or a view in general) from a task (in lib/) to update the bar?

FYI I use ActiveAdmin too, that not simply the problem, because it uses precompiled views.

Comment: is this task a REST action or a Rake TASK?

Comment: @Rogier This is a Rake Task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a new REST action (or ideally reuse an existing one) in a controller to provide the information for the progress bar.

And I would also try to invoke the controller with Ajax using JQuery at interval of times.

I think that this way of facing the progress bar implementation is a better idea than invoking a view from a lib task.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(updateProgressBar, 1000);
});
function updateProgressBar() {
  //Invoke controller with ajax, and update progressBar
}
```

If you don't like playing with polling in the client, you may find interesting server events in HTML5.

Comment: +1 for the solution, but I would like to avoid async process like calling a function by a setInterval

Answer (score 0):

It's a post from a while ago, but in case it helps someone there's a gem that does that. It doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, but it's a good example on how to implement the requested behaviour:

https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job